# Clearing multiple directory - streamline current code

Tags: batch-file

I'm using a batch file to delete out files and folders in set directories. but want to know if there is a way to streamline the current code to only a couple of lines or so instead of repeating each line for different directories.

Below is my current code.

```
@echo off

DEL /A /F/Q /S "C:\Users\Testing\Documents\*.*"
FOR /D %%p IN ("C:\Users\Testing\Documents\*.*")  DO RD "%%p" /S /Q
DEL /A /F/Q /S "C:\Users\Testing\Downloads\*.*"
FOR /D %%p IN ("C:\Users\Testing\Downloads\*.*")  DO RD "%%p" /S /Q
DEL /A /F/Q /S "C:\Users\Testing\My Pictures\*.*"
FOR /D %%p IN ("C:\Users\Testing\My Pictures\*.*")  DO RD "%%p" /S /Q
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the `RD /S /Q` command will delete all the files in the subdirectories, so you can remove the `/S` option from the `DEL` command.

Now to your actual question - of course there is a better way :-)

The generic solution for arbitrarily complex code is to put all of the common code in a subroutine that takes one or more arguments, and then call the subroutine for each set of unique arguments. Be sure to include an `exit /b` before any of your subroutines to make sure that your main script does not fall into the subroutine code without making a call.

```
@echo off
call :del "C:\Users\Testing\Documents"
call :del "C:\Users\Testing\Downloads"
call :del "C:\Users\Testing\My Pictures"
exit /b

:del
del /a /f /q /s "%~1\*.*"
for /d %%p in ("%~1\*.*") do rd /s /q "%%p"
exit /b
```

If you wanted, you could add an extra FOR loop to iterate your files, and then you only need one CALL statement.

```
@echo off
for %%P in (
  "C:\Users\Testing\Documents"
  "C:\Users\Testing\Downloads"
  "C:\Users\Testing\My Pictures"
) do call :del %%P
exit /b

:del
del /a /f /q /s "%~1\*.*"
for /d %%p in ("%~1\*.*") do rd /s /q "%%p"
exit /b
```

But since your common code is so simple, I recommend moving the subroutine code inside the outer DO block by adding parentheses:

```
@echo off
for %%P in (
  "C:\Users\Testing\Documents"
  "C:\Users\Testing\Downloads"
  "C:\Users\Testing\My Pictures"
) do (
  del /a /f /q /s "%%~P\*.*"
  for /d %%p in ("%%~P\*.*") do rd /s /q "%%p"
)
```

This does not really reduce the number of lines in your case, but it makes the repetitive nature of your script more obvious and easier to manage. And it will reduce lines of code as you add more paths in your outer loop.

Comment: As didactic as ever.

Comment: As far as I'm aware @Dave, `Del`'s `/A` option works the same way as it does in `Dir`, chosing it without selecting individual attributes selects all of the options. To explain using `Dir` as an example `Dir /A` will output Read-only, Hidden, System and Reparse Points among others. If you use `/A-H` it would output all types except for hidden.

Comment: @compo - Thanks for the correction. More importantly, `DEL` or `DIR` without `/A` will exclude hidden files. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Dave, I might also suggest using **`\*`** instead of **`\*.*`**, just because filenames don't necessarily need to have an extension, and conversely directory names may not include a period.

Comment: @Compo - In the interest of backward compatibility with DOS, Windows treats `*.*` identically to `*`. So either form will work.

Comment: _I understand that it is not a necessary change Dave, it's just that the OP wanted it streamlining and catering for options which are, (based upon the OP's provided paths), at best, highly unlikely, didn't seem to me to have embraced the intended criteria._

Answer (score 2):

```cmd
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%a in ( 
        "C:\Users\Testing\Documents" 
        "C:\Users\Testing\Downloads" 
        "C:\Users\Testing\My Pictures"
    ) do pushd %%a && (
        rmdir . /s /q
        popd
    )
```

Using a `for` command to iterate the list of folders. For each folder in list try to change active directory to the current element in list (`pushd`) and if it can be done (conditional execution operator `&&`) then remove anything inside (`rmdir . /s /q`) and restore previous active directory (`popd`)

**note** In previous code the `rmdir . /s /q` tries to remove anything inside the folder AND the folder itself. The folder can not be removed as we have set it as the current active directory by `pushd` usage. As pointed in comments by dbenham that means that `rmdir` will show a error message saying the folder can not be removed as it is in use. While it is the intended behaviour (folder protection, not error message), maybe it is desirable to hide the error message. This can be done by redirecting the error output stream (stream 2) to `nul` device:

```
    ...
    ) do pushd %%a && (
        rmdir . /s /q 2>nul 
        popd
    )
```

This will hide any error (expected or not) associated with the `rmdir` command.

This technique can be extended to hide any error in previous code (if you include a non existing folder the `pushd` also shows an error).

```cmd
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    2>nul (
        for %%a in ( 
            "C:\Users\Testing\Documents" 
            "C:\Users\Testing\Downloads" 
            "C:\Users\Testing\My Pictures"
        ) do pushd %%a && (
            rmdir . /s /q
            popd
        )
    )
```

Or, if you prefer a selective error reporting (dbenham's idea), it can be extended as:

```cmd
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%a in ( 
        "C:\Users\Testing\Documents" 
        "C:\Users\Testing\Downloads" 
        "C:\Users\Testing\My Pictures"
    ) do ( 2>nul pushd "%%~a" ) && (
        rmdir . /s /q 2>&1 | findstr /lb "."
        popd
    )
```

that will hide the errors in `pushd` command (if the folder does not exist there is no need to clean it) and will show any errors in the `rmdir` command related to any non removable element except the current active directory.

Comment: I like your PUSHD/POPD optimization. However, your RMDIR attempts to delete the current directory as well with an error. But the end result is correct. You probably should redirect stderr to nul.

Comment: @dbenham, If I would use the code I have to agree with you. But as the original code did not include any error hiding I also didn't include it. Anyway, something to include in the answer, thank you.

Comment: The disadvantage of redirecting stderr to null is it will mask any other errors that might crop up. For example, if another process has one of the subdirectories as its active directory, then that directory removal will fail with an additional error.

Comment: The problem with the error message related to the root path is that the error for that path is expected/desired. Generally you don't want to see error messages if the end result is what you want.

Comment: The unwanted error message can be selectively removed by using `rmdir . /s /q 2>&1 | findstr /lb .`

Comment: @dbenham, Very nice! I didn't realize the output in `rd` matching the path format used in command line. Something new learned.

Comment: After investigating [Compo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54276914/clearing-multiple-directory-streamline-current-code/54277330#comment95377650_54277330) about the `/A` option, I discovered that your solution will remove hidden directories, whereas mine (and the OP's original) will not. Very interesting...

Comment: @dbenham, Yes, I already knew it. OP's code does not remove first level hidden folders (`for /d` does not enumerate them) but remove any third or lower hidden folders (`rd /s /q`). OP has (and already uses) two different behaviours to select or combine as needed.